# Drawing a graph in a Windows Forms application using the dot.exe process - possible out of memory error

Tags: c#, winforms, graph, graphviz, dot

I call a drawing function that I wrote on the data that I need for drawing a graph.
The drawing function works like this: First it creates a text file. It's basically a .dot file, meaning that Graphviz / dot.exe knows how to handle it. The generated file looks something like this:

```
graph{
resolution=1000;
1[
label ="" 
pos = "552,552!"
width = 0.002
height = 0.002
fixedsize=true
fontsize = 8
color =red
penwidth = 0.1, color = black, shape = box, width = 0.07, height = 0.07, label = ""
]
74[
label ="" 
pos = "450,552!"
width = 0.002
height = 0.002
fixedsize=true
fontsize = 8
color =red
shape = point
]
(...)
1 -- 74[penwidth = 0.099, color="red"]
74 -- 40[penwidth = 0.099, color="red"]
40 -- 32[penwidth = 0.099, color="red"]
32 -- 18[penwidth = 0.099, color="red"]
(...)
}
```

After it generates the file, the function calls the dot.exe process with the following flags:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("dot.exe");
startInfo.Arguments = "-Kneato -Goverlap=prism -Tpng " + fileName + ".txt -o " + fileName + ".png";
```

I've tried using different flags, image formats etc., but none of that solves my problem.

My application basically consists of an interface with a few buttons and two PictureBoxes.   Clicking on one of the buttons causes the "important part of the program" to execute.
The "important part" takes some time to execute, so I used a BackgroundWorker for that. What happens over there (in the backgroundWorker1_DoWork function) is:
Some things get calculated and my drawing function gets called twice on the resulting data. It creates two images and "puts them" into the PictureBoxes.

And it works just fine for most data, but for some data it doesn't. On some of the data, no pictures get shown in the PictureBoxes. When I check the folder where the text files and the images should have been created, I see that only the text file and the resulting picture which should go into the first PictureBox are created... But not even they are shown. My conclusion is that something makes the whole BackgroundWorker process stop, probably some kind of an error in the dot.exe process.
Now, every time the process gets called, a console appears for a glimpse of a second. Some useful data might be displayed over there, but I don't know how to read it.

There's a previous and slightly different version of my application, which doesn't work on the same data that the current version fails to work on.
In the old version, however, I'm able to read the console output (probably because the whole program crashes), and it says something along the lines of:

```
Graph is too large for cairo renderer bitmaps.   
Scaling by 0.4 to fit dot: failure to create cairo surface: out of memory.
```

I get this error *mostly* for larger graphs, but not *only* for larger graphs. Some larger graphs work just fine, and some smaller ones don't. And none of them are particulary large anyway: The largest are approximately 80 nodes large. I thought it might have something to do with resolution or something like that, but whatever parameter I change, the thing still doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea on what I should try? Do you need any extra information about my problem?

Edit: Also, changing the size using the -G attribute doesn't help. In fact, whatever I do I always get the *exact* same error, meaning that the scaling factor mentioned in the error doesn't change.

Comment: First step is to manually call the `dot.exe` process and feed it the text file as you would in the program. I haven't used Graphviz for a couple years but I did use it in university for a class so I'm familiar with it. If you run it from the console without any errors (it produces a picture) then we can take a look at your code. You might have a syntax error in the .dot file which the console window is telling you but closes too quick.

Comment: @TheCapn: How can I manually call the dot.exe process?

Comment: Open a command prompt, and give it the command the same you would in code: `dot.exe -Kneato -Goverlap=prism -Tpng <INPUT_FILE>.txt -o <OUTPUT_FILE>.png`   replace the filenames to what you want them named as. You'll probably need to navigate to the directory where your input file is first (`cd` command) and `dot.exe` would need to be on your PATH variable

Comment: @TheCapn: Thanks. If I run this from cmd, the first graph gets generated without an error (note that it also gets generated if I run it from my application, but it doesn't get displayed in my form). For the second graph I can't try this because my program doesn't even manage to generate the needed .dot file (note that this happens only for some, usually larger, inputs... for the rest of them, everything gets generated/drawn/shown perfectly).

Comment: So, to recap. 1) You can call dot.exe manually on all inputs you have just fine, but it fails from the program? 2)Extremely large inputs are failing to produce a .dot file? You don't get to the stage where you want to call the dot.exe application?

Comment: @TheCapn: 1) Yes, and it fails from the program only for some (usually larger) graphs. 2) Not exactly. In my program, I choose a file which contains information about the positions of nodes and things like that. Then my program does two things: It finds a way to connect the nodes AND it reads the optimal way to connect the nodes from a file. Then it calls my drawing function twice - once to produce a graph for the solution it found and once to produce a graph for the optimal solution. Then it displays the two graphs in my form. It all works on some inputs...

Comment: ...but, on some other inputs, the graph for the solution which the program found gets generated but not displayed and the graph for the optimal solution doesn't even get generated (because the .dot file doesn't get generated). Sounds strange? It does to me.

Comment: If the call to generate the dot file on the first call fails for whatever reason it kind of makes sense that the following calls get messed up too. Unfortunately it seems your issue is a bit beyond what I can help with. The error you posted turned up a bunch of links on discussions in google so that might be a place to start. They talk about using a size attribute? Again, sorry I can't help further

Comment: It doesn't get messed up on the first call. The first call produces a perfectly fine .dot file, and a perfectly fine graph. The problem is that the program won't display that graph. The thing that's *really* puzzling is that, if I remove the first call from my code, the second call *still* won't produce a .dot file. It's as if there's a problem with both calls, but more with the first call than the second, BUT on some inputs everything works just fine. Anyway, thanks for trying to help, I might use our discussion to provide more info in my question. As I mention in my post, changing the size..

Comment: ...attribute doesn't help, nor does anything else I found while googling.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my problem was nothing Graphviz or even graph specific - I was testing my (metaheuristic) algorithm on the test examples I found online. When reading the optimal solution files line by line and splitting them into words, `""` would sometimes get recognized as a word.